# Which one is your priority? Writing thesis or writing academic paper

Tags: publications, phd, thesis, thesis-committee

Which one do you recommend and why? 1: Finish writing PhD dissertation and extract papers from your thesis. 2. Start writing papers and complete your thesis based on your papers?

Comment: Varies by field.  For example, in the humanities you generally finish your Ph.D., then re-work your thesis into a book published a few years later.

Comment: Can you please state your field?

Answer (score 3):

There's no single right answer here.

For instance, if your department allows you to submit a "stapler thesis" that consists of submitted and published manuscripts, then it makes all the sense in the world to write the papers and then submit them as your thesis. On the other hand, if you can't do a stapler thesis and have to submit your thesis in just a few months, there's no sense in pausing to write complete manuscripts.

Similarly, if you're relatively early on in your career, there's no sense in waiting for the PhD to publish (in fact, this would be a spectacularly *bad* idea, since you'd give other people time to publish ahead of you).

So, basically, you need to consider your relative progress in the PhD program, what is and isn't allowed in your thesis, and what the ramifications of not publishing immediately are before making that decision. Of course, you should also discuss this with your advisor, who may have some additional insight.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that there is no single right answer. This is just an additional issue to consider.

There is some advantage to publishing at least one paper while still a graduate student. There is a process to matching up target venue and paper content, preparing a paper for submission, submitting it, and taking it through review and revisions. It varies depending on the field and type of research. Going through that process with access to an advisor who has done it many times for papers in your field and is familiar with your research may be the easiest way to learn it.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK (at least at one university), apparently one of the "boxes to tick" on the examination form is "is this publishable" - hence having at least one paper is considered good practice to have that box ticked. - However there is no explicit requirement to publish papers to obtain a PhD and people have obtained PhDs without submitting papers.

The reality is that most supervisors and universities will encourage PhD students to publish - or try to, on the one hand as it ticks the box on the other as it mean another publication to the supervisors name (despite being just a co-author).
The downside of this is that quantity over quantity is favoured - or you may end up writing papers you don't believe are finished or yet good enough... - but that's a different philosophical discussion.

As to your question:
You should check the requirements for your degree with your university first.

- IF there is significant benefit to having published at least one paper (such as the UK "ticks the box"), you should possibly see that you publish one paper.
- In the UK your chapters should not be identical to a paper - they could be the paper plus extra stuff though. Nonetheless, excluding university regulations, having a chapter identical to a paper may be problematic if you wish to make your thesis publicly available (paper copyright) and also brings up the point of "self plagiarism" - so you need to reference your own paper.
- As a result you possibly don't want both documents to be identical. (Thesis and paper)

Some other points to consider:

- If you leave academia you may not have the time to publish the papers - even though you planned to publish them. (I believe someone else had this experience here on Academia Stackexchange).
- And lastly, your supervisors might not want you to submit before you have published a paper - obviously they can't force you but finishing a PhD in a fight isn't ideal (in fact this applies to me in a way... I have to wait until a paper with a colleague is in before I can or should submit... - but again, that's another discussion).